# coordinate computation of the image thumbnail

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-graphics

This is a code snippet for creating a thumbnail sized image (from an original large image) and placing it appropriately on top of a tableviewcell. As i was studying the code i got stuck at the part where the thumbnail is being given a position by setting its abscissa and ordinate. In the method **-(void)setThumbDataFromImage:(UIImage *)image** they're setting the dimensions and coordinate for project thumbnail—

```
   -(void)setThumbnailDataFromImage:(UIImage *)image{
CGSize origImageSize= [image size];

      //    the rectange of the thumbnail
         CGRect newRect= CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40);

   //    figure out a scaling ratio to make sure we maintain the same aspect ratio
         float ratio= MAX(newRect.size.width/origImageSize.width,   newRect.size.height/origImageSize.height);

  //       Create a transparent bitmap context with a scaling factor equal to that of the screen
     UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newRect.size, NO, 0.0);

    //    create a path that is a rounded rectangle
     UIBezierPath *path= [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:newRect cornerRadius:5.0];
    //    make all the subsequent drawing to clip to this rounded rectangle
       [path addClip];

    //    center the image in the thumbnail rectangle
      CGRect projectRect;
     projectRect.size.width=ratio * origImageSize.width;
     projectRect.size.height= ratio * origImageSize.height;
     projectRect.origin.x= (newRect.size.width- projectRect.size.width)/2;
     projectRect.origin.y= (newRect.size.height- projectRect.size.height)/2;

    //    draw the image on it
      [image drawInRect:projectRect];

     //    get the image from the image context, keep it as our thumbnail
      UIImage *smallImage= UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
       [self setThumbnail:smallImage];

     //    get the PNG representation of the image and set it as our archivable data
         NSData *data= UIImagePNGRepresentation(smallImage);
         [self setThumbnailData:data];

      //    Cleanup image context resources, we're done
       UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
```

I got the width and height computation wherein we multiply the origImageSize with scaling factor/ratio.
But then we use the following to give the thumbnail a position—

```
     projectRect.origin.x= (newRect.size.width- projectRect.size.width)/2;
     projectRect.origin.y= (newRect.size.height- projectRect.size.height)/2;
```

This i fail to understand. I cannot wrap my head around it.  :? 
Is this part of the centering process. I mean, are we using a mathematical relation here to position the thumbnail or is it some random calculation i.e could have been anything.. Am i missing some fundamental behind these two lines of code??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two lines are standard code for centering something, although they aren’t quite written in the most general way. You normally want to use:

```
 projectRect.origin.x = newRect.origin.x + newRect.size.width / 2.0 - projectRect.size.width / 2.0;
 projectRect.origin.y = newRect.origin.y + newRect.size.height / 2.0 - projectRect.size.height / 2.0;
```

In your case the author knows the origin is 0,0, so they omitted the first term in each line.

Since to center a rectangle in another rectangle you want the centers of the two axes to line up, you take, say, half the container’s width (the center of the outer rectangle) and subtract half the inner rectangle’s width (which takes you to the left side of the inner rectangle), and that gives you where the inner rectangle’s left side should be (e.g.: its x origin) when it is correctly centered.

Comment: so its for aligning the centers of the newRect (outer rect) and projRect (inner rect) together. `projRect.origin.x= newRect.origin.x + newRect.size.center.x - projRect.size.width/2`; and `projRect.origin.y= newRect.origin.y + newRect.size.center.y - projRect.size.height/2`. But what if the projRect is rectangular in shape (consider the origImage to be rectangular)? Then we would have the centers of the inner square and the outer rectangle aligned but the rectangle's origin wouldn't be at (0,0). So wouldn't the rectangle get cut off in the edges if shown on a tableviewcell while running.

Comment: In the rectangle scenario consider the width to be same as the square's but height bigger than the square's(newRect being 40X40).. So the thumbnail would shift up the cell and be out of place. So wouldn't it be a problem.

Comment: If the inner content is bigger than the outer it’s going to get cropped by this code. I assume the author’s definition of “thumbnail” is “an image up to 40x40”.

Comment: Yeah i mistook the 40X40 newRect as inner rectangle. What i meant to say was that it was the outer rect (serving as the container). The projRect being the inner rect (it is the contained item acting as placeholder for the image) of lets say 40X50 dimension (considering the origImage itself as rectangular in shape),would get its upper part cropped off.

Comment: So the process behind creating a thumbnail is to first create a container (generally a square) and give it a place in the coordinate space. Then create a thumbnail frame (the inner rect/contained item) by maintaining the aspect ratio of the original image and then give it a place in the coordinate system w.r.t the container (by aligning the centers). Once the thumbnail placeholder is ready, tack the into it. Please tell me if i'm missing something..

Comment: No, I was just explaining those two lines. The process is you figure out the biggest version of the input image that will fit in 40x40, given that the input image might not be square but you don’t want to mess up its aspect ratio. So, first you figure out which axis on the input image is bigger, then you scale it down (if it’s bigger than 40x40) so the larger axis ends up being 40 exactly (the smaller axis will be less), then you make sure this smaller image is centered inside the 40x40 target.

Comment: yeah now i got it..thanx a ton man... especially for the mathematical equations. It did feel a bit confusing at first but then i drew up the whole thing on a paper and then it made sense to add newRect.origin.x or newRect.origin.y for placing projRect on the coordinate system relative to newRect. It really helped.. Thanx again man...

Comment: Hold on a sec.. you say we have to keep the larger axis at max i.e 40. Now here's a scenario– lets say the originalImage= 100X200. the container size is 40X40 So, after computation, we have scaling factor as 2/5. {MAX(40/100,40/200)}= 2/5.. So projRect.size.width= 2/5 * 100= 40. and projRect.size.height= 1/5 * 200= 80. So projRect.size= (40X80) .. Now you said the maximum side needs to be 40, so the min side<40. But this scenario (40X80), we get max side> 40.. I'm just a bit confused on this part. Please assist. I know its frustrating. i want to get this sorted out and have it crystal-clear.

Comment: I agree, the code looks wrong to me, it should be MIN(). I wonder if the original author only tested it on square images?

Comment: Its BNR (Big Nerd Ranch) iOS Programming 3rd ed.. Yeah if the original image is square then MAX() makes sense.. Coz using MIN() in the code above follows **what you mentioned about 40 being the max side and that the min side will naturally become less than 40. This applies perfectly to a rectangular image**. I guess the author took the square image thing as a general scenario.

Comment: You should write them and tell them...it’s easy to flip MIN() and MAX(), I do it all the time. Good on you for making sure you understood the code instead of just using it blindly.